# How do directories in the NDK home folder relate to the NDK version?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, standard-library

My `$NDK_HOME` folder contains different implementations of the standard library.

```
qdii@nomada /opt/android-ndk/platforms $ ls -l
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 5 root android 4096  3 déc.  19:18 android-14
drwxr-xr-x 3 root android 4096 30 déc.  18:42 android-3
drwxr-xr-x 3 root android 4096 30 déc.  18:42 android-4
drwxr-xr-x 3 root android 4096 30 déc.  18:42 android-5
drwxr-xr-x 3 root android 4096 30 déc.  18:42 android-8
drwxr-xr-x 5 root android 4096  3 déc.  19:18 android-9
```

Each one of these different directories contain a version of the standard library. For a custom project that is built without using `ndk-build`, I would like to know which one to use.

Say my project uses the NDK version 8d, which implementation of the standard library should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, they're tagged by API level. So you should use the one corresponding to the minimal API level your app is targeting.